# localhost times out - Windows Server 2008

Tags: networking, iis, localhost, windows

I'm having a weird problem accessing a local web site.

Web site is mapped to a hostname e.g. example.org
The hostname works perfectly on any external machine, but not locally.

**When trying to access the hostname locally or try and access localhost, the browser just hangs.**

---

This is the hosts file

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

---

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: what IP is returned when you ping the hostname from the machine? Does it match the IP if you do it from an external system that works? Your IIS binding is probably not setup to listen on 127.0.0.1 which would explain why localhost doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simplify the problem. A couple major things to check:

1. netstat -an -> Are you listening to 127.0.0.1?
2. telnet to the port -> bypass browser and proxy config problems
3. URL should be http:/127.0.0.1/ -> Bypass name resolution

If it still doesn't work, check your web server config. There are several ways IIS can be configured to not work in this situation.